# dynamic from statement based on column name

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, user-defined-functions

Background info:
I got ms access 2010 database with >10 (and growing) linked tables, sources: csv & xls from scattered tools that needs to be combined and queried. The sources are 'dirty' and I use insert queries with additional code to clean them and store the records in a local table with indexing for better performance later. The local tables are emptied first with a delete query. The insert queries are logged with a data macro `After Insert: LogEvent` on the local table in USysApplicationLog. *Data macro produces loads of records in USysApplicationLog, while 1 per table per insert would be sufficient for my cause. Open issue, but less important at this time.*

The local tables have the same name as the linked table with the postfix "-local".
Examples: csvMachines / cvsMachines-local, csvCustomers / csvCustomers-local, etc.

At the moment I'm manually checking everything, doing all the queries, etc. But looking for a way to automate this more.

Before using the database with local tables I want to check if:

- the local tables are up to date
  *got this kinda covered with querying the USysApplicationLog and UDF function to check modification date of sources*
- the local tables are filled
  *reason for my question here*

Looking for a smart way (sql, vba or udf) to combine following working query

```
SELECT MSysObjects.NAME AS LinkedTableName
    ,[LinkedTableName] & "-local" AS LocalTableName
FROM MSysObjects
WHERE (((MSysObjects.DATABASE) IS NOT NULL));
```

with a simple `SELECT count(*)` per local table name.

Tried following but Access can't find LocalTableName as table.

```
SELECT MSysObjects.NAME AS LinkedTableName
    ,[LinkedTableName] & "-local" AS LocalTableName
    ,(
        SELECT count(*)
        FROM [LocalTableName]
        ) AS LocalTableRecordCount
FROM MSysObjects
WHERE (((MSysObjects.DATABASE) IS NOT NULL));
```

Looked at old similar questions as [Create table - dynamic name of table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145933/create-table-dynamic-name-of-table) and [MS Access query with dynamic from statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495377/ms-access-query-with-dynamic-from-statements), but didnt see how to implement their solutions in my situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking for a solution for another issue, I found an alternative anwser for this question in the [Access Help](http://office.microsoft.com/client/helppreview14.aspx?AssetId=HV080200498&lcid=2057&NS=MSACCESS%2EDEV&Version=14&tl=2&respos=0&CTT=1&queryid=7de8c968%2D3a06%2D4a74%2D836f%2D6b80a694e699): `expression.DCount(Expr, Domain, Criteria)`

Working query for my situation:

```
SELECT MSysObjects.NAME AS LinkedTableName
    ,[LinkedTableName] & "-local" AS LocalTableName
    ,DCount("*", [LinkedTableName] & "-local") AS LocalTableRecordCount
FROM MSysObjects
WHERE (((MSysObjects.DATABASE) IS NOT NULL));
```

Answer (score 2):

Access will not let you provide a name for the `FROM` data source at runtime.  It just does not support that capability.

Since you have a VBA tag on this question, perhaps you would consider a procedure which loops through your table names and retrieves the record count for each.

For each table name ...

```vb
strSelect = "SELECT Count(*) FROM " & LocalTableName
MsgBox CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSelect)(0)
```

Or look at the `TableDef.RecordCount` property ...

```vb
MsgBox CurrentDb.TableDefs(LocalTableName).RecordCount
```